# angular rewrite url in html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome-extension, url-rewriting

now I work in a case to write chrome extension in gmail, and our extension use UI-router for change view, it change url from xxx/#inbox to xxx/#/inbox, that would block another extension features(Streak) while customer expect to use in the same time. so we enable html5 mode, and rewrite the url to make it work. here is the rewrite part:

```
app.config(function($provide,$locationProvider,....){
    $provide.decorator('$browser', function($delegate) {
            var superUrl = $delegate.url;
            $delegate.url = function(url, replace) {
                if(url !== undefined) {
                    return superUrl(url.replace(/\%2F/g,"/"), replace);
                } else {
                    return superUrl().replace(/\//, "%2F");
                }
            }
            return $delegate;
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false,
            rewriteLinks: true
    });
    ......
})
```

it works fine with our part extension, but while I click Streak feature, it would cause error

lib.js:17317 Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D][error-link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D)

like Infinite $digest Loop
any suggestion to fix this?